# Trying to install gatsby.js, getting a lot of errors

Tags: node.js, npm, gatsby

This is what happens when I try to install **gatsby-cli** globally:

Is it actually a permission issue? or did I missed something?

> npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.10: core-js@<3.0 is no longer
>   maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues.
>   Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
>   npm WARN ink@2.6.0 requires a peer of @types/react@>=16.8.0 but none
>   is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
>   auto-bind@3.0.0 requires a peer of @types/react@>=16.8.0 but none is
>   installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm ERR! code EACCES npm ERR! syscall symlink npm ERR! path
>   ../lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/lib/index.js npm ERR! dest
>   /usr/local/bin/gatsby npm ERR! errno -13 npm ERR! Error: EACCES:
>   permission denied, symlink
>   '../lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/lib/index.js' ->
>   '/usr/local/bin/gatsby' npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EACCES:
>   permission denied, symlink
>   '../lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/lib/index.js' ->
>   '/usr/local/bin/gatsby'] { npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EACCES:
>   permission denied, symlink
>   '../lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/lib/index.js' ->
>   '/usr/local/bin/gatsby'] { npm ERR!     errno: -13, npm ERR!     code:
>   'EACCES', npm ERR!     syscall: 'symlink', npm ERR!     path:
>   '../lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/lib/index.js', npm ERR!     dest:
>   '/usr/local/bin/gatsby' npm ERR!   }, npm ERR!   stack: "Error:
>   EACCES: permission denied, symlink
>   '../lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/lib/index.js' ->
>   '/usr/local/bin/gatsby'", npm ERR!   errno: -13, npm ERR!   code:
>   'EACCES', npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink', npm ERR!   path:
>   '../lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/lib/index.js', npm ERR!   dest:
>   '/usr/local/bin/gatsby' npm ERR! } npm ERR!  npm ERR! The operation
>   was rejected by your operating system. npm ERR! It is likely you do
>   not have the permissions to access this file as the current user npm
>   ERR!  npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue,
>   please double-check the npm ERR! permissions of the file and its
>   containing directories, or try running npm ERR! the command again as
>   root/Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

solve it using below

`sudo npm i -g gatsby-cli`

Comment: It is NOT recommeded to use `sudo npm`.